# java program to Increment Suffix and prefix Number in String

Tags: java

```
String s1 = "001abcd";
String s2 = "abcd001";
```

**Input** : s1 = ‘001abcd’

**Output** : 002abcd

**Explanation** : Prefix 001 incremented to 002.

---

**Input** : s2 = ‘abcd001’

**Output** : abcd002

**Explanation** : Suffix 001 incremented to 002.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions

Comment: Besides your incorrect use of the terms suffix and prefix, you should show what you tried to solve that task and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 1):

## Write a class

Rather than thinking terms of text (strings, prefix, suffix), think in terms of objects.

You are representing two pieces of information: Some kind of label alongside a serial number. So write a class representing those two pieces.

### `record`

In Java 16 and later, you might write your class something like this [record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395). A record is a brief way to write a class whose main purpose is to communicate data transparently and immutably. The compiler implicitly creates default implementations of constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`.

We have a constructor that validates the input data, replacing the default constructor of a `record`. And we have a method that returns your formatted string. Lastly, we have an `increment` method that constructs and returns a new object, per [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) design.

Of course you would change my `NumberedLabel` class name to something appropriate to your [problem domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_domain).

```java
package work.basil.demo.stuff;

import java.util.Objects;

public record NumberedLabel(String label , int number)
{
    // Constructor, to validate inputs.
    public NumberedLabel ( final String label , final int number )
    {
        Objects.requireNonNull( label );
        if ( label.isBlank() ) { throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Label cannot be empty." ); }
        if ( number < 1 ) { throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Label cannot be zero or negative." ); }
        if ( number > 1_000 ) { throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Label must be under 1,000." ); }
        this.label = label;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String format ( )
    {
        return this.label + String.format( "%03d" , this.number );
    }

    public NumberedLabel increment ( )
    {
        if ( this.number == 999 )
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException( "Cannot increment beyond the current number of " + this.number + "." );
        } else
        {
            int newNumber = ( this.number + 1 );
            return new NumberedLabel( this.label , newNumber );
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage.

```java
NumberedLabel x = new NumberedLabel( "abcd" , 1 );
NumberedLabel y = x.increment();

System.out.println( "x = " + x + "  |  formatted = " + x.format() );
System.out.println( "y = " + y + "  |  formatted = " + y.format() );
```

When run.

```
x = NumberedLabel[label=abcd, number=1]  |  formatted = abcd001
y = NumberedLabel[label=abcd, number=2]  |  formatted = abcd002
```

You might want to add a `canIncrement` method returning `true` if the number is below 999.

If you must start with your strings as inputs, then add a static `parse` method to pull apart the string into two pieces. Use those pieces to construct and return an object of our `NumberedLabel` class. Writing [`static` methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html), and [chopping a string into substrings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/manipstrings.html), are two topics that have been covered *many* times on Stack Overflow, so search to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
static final Pattern NUMBER = Pattern.compile("\\d+");

static String increment(String s) {
    return NUMBER.matcher(s).replaceFirst(
        m -> String.format("%0" + m.group().length() + "d",
            Integer.parseInt(m.group()) + 1));
}
```

and

```
String s1 = "001abcd";
String s2 = "abcd001";
System.out.println(increment(s1));
System.out.println(increment(s2));
System.out.println(increment("abcde987654321fg"));
```

output:

```
002abcd
abcd002
abcde987654322fg
```

Comment: thanks sir for helping